# How would I execute class A's run method from class B

Tags: java, class, swt

```
public class AplotPdfPrintLocal extends ApplicationWindow {
private String userSelectedFile;

public AplotPdfPrintLocal(String pdfFilePath) {
   super(null);
   this.userSelectedFile = pdfFilePath;
}

public void run() {
   setBlockOnOpen(true);
   open();
   Display.getCurrent().dispose();
}

etc........
```

I want to execute the above class from Class B

Method is class B - below

```
public void startPDFPrint() throws Exception {
      AplotPdfPrintLocal pdfPrint = new AplotPdfPrintLocal(getPDFFileName()).run();
}
```

I am getting a error that I need to change the return type of run from void to plotPdfPrintLocal

Am I going about calling the class wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change it to:

```
public void startPDFPrint() throws Exception {
      AplotPdfPrintLocal pdfPrint = new AplotPdfPrintLocal(getPDFFileName());
      pdfPrint.run();
}
```

or

```
public void startPDFPrint() throws Exception {
      new AplotPdfPrintLocal(getPDFFileName()).run();
}
```

what the compiler is saying is that you're trying to assign the result of the run method (**void**) to left member of the expression, the **AplotPdfPrintLocal pdfPrint** variable.

So, due to the fact that **run** is "returning" **void**, there is an error, a discrepancy between the expected **AplotPdfPrintLocal** type (declared on the left side) and the actual return type: **void**.